# Type 'V' is not assignable to type 'V'. [2719]

Tags: typescript, types

I'm having an issue with TypeScript that I can't work out (the error message is very vague). Here's the code that's creating an error:

```ts
type Reducer<V,T> = (accumulator: V, value: V, index: number, collection: T) => V;
class Collection< K, V > extends Map < K, V > {
  reduce < V > (reducer: Reducer < V, this > , initialValue ? : V): V {
    const {
      length
    } = arguments;
    let index = 1,
      iterator = this.values(),
      accumulator: V = initialValue;

    if (length < 2) {
      // No initialValue was passed.
      index = 0;
      // Jump over an item, which is the
      // new value of `initialValue`.
      accumulator = iterator.next().value;
    }

    for (let value of iterator) {
      // `accumulator` being the accumulator.
      accumulator = reducer(accumulator, initialValue, index, this);
      ++index;
    }

    return accumulator;
  }
}
```

The error message that appears is:

```
    [ts] Type 'V' is not assignable to type 'V'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated. [2719]
```

What's the issue here? `V` is the same type, so i don't see the issue with my code.

Comment: It's complaining about `accumulator: V = initialValue;`?

Comment: The error is still raised if I remove it.

Comment: If you try `class Collection extends Map {`

Comment: Fixed the issue.

Comment: How are they different types? They're in the same scope. UPDATE: Just threw in a `@ts-ignore`. Until I get an answer that fixes that, I'll be ok with that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `class Collection extends Map {`

The `extends Map < K, V >` is probably registering types `K` and `V` as outer objects to be defined. So it isn't the same as what you are using within function.

For example, let's say Java since it's an OOP lang, a class that uses generics expects those generics to be passed on into the function. When you say `extends Map < K, V >`, it is the same. It expects `K` and `V` in the function header to be almost like an input. Whilst `K` and `V` that you use inside the function is something like a variable that you use within the function.

Comment: Could you explain this further?

Comment: This answer should not be used with **Type**Script because it disables type-checking for `Map` methods.

Comment: @WillHoskings Fixed!

Comment: It isn't fixed, so I'll elaborate. I want `Map#set`, `Map#get` to not be loosely typed. I want to restrict the value types to the generic types, so it's type safe.

Comment: For example, `Map<number, string>` wouldn't let you do `set("hello", []);`, but `Map` would. Trying to break this down :)